# Dax - Select latest price per item in purchase history

Tags: dax

[image]

This formula is hit/miss returning correct value sometimes.  In the picture you can see it is returning correctly 50% of the time....

```
t.LatestUnit$ =
VAR _LatestItem =
    MAX ( 'Test'[Cat#-UOM] )
RETURN
    MAXX (
        FILTER ( ALL ( 'Test' ), 'Test'[Cat#-UOM] = _LatestItem ),
        'Test'[UNIT $]
    )
```

Answer (score 0):

You should try something like this:

```
LatestPricePerItem =
VAR vMaxOrderDate = MAX ( 'Table'[OrderDate] )
RETURN
    CALCULATE (
        MAX ( 'Table'[UNIT $] ),
        FILTER ( 'Table', 'Table'[OrderDate] = vMaxOrderDate )
    )
```

Instead of getting the max item, you need to get the max date for each item and because you are using a table visual, there is no problem with some type of context.

[image]